# Inline for loops in Julia

Tags: for-loop, julia

I think you are encouraged to use these kind of `for` loops in Julia:

```
b = [i+1 for i in [1,2,3]]
```

but I wonder why, apart from more compact syntax which leads to better
readability. Are these inline for loops more efficient to evaluate
expressions? If yes, why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These `for` loops are called *array comprehensions*. They are a simple notation for a common programming pattern of allocating an array and then filling each element with a value based on some calculation.

Doing this without a comprehension is possible and probably about as fast if done correctly (removing unnecessary bounds checks with @inbounds). For the example in the question, the following code does the same:

```
let tmp = [1,2,3], len = length(tmp)
    b = Vector{Int}(len)
    @inbounds for (n,i) in enumerate(tmp)
        b[n] = i+1
    end
    b
end
```

In most cases using the form in the question is a win for both performance and readability.

Comment: An alternative form is vector broadcasting, which doesn't look so nice in this case though, but can look really clear: `add1(x) = x+1; add1.(1:3)` (notice the dot between the function and the brackets).

Answer (score 5):

As a complementary to @Dan Getz's answer, in practice, another advantage of using comprehension is that we don't need to explicitly care about types, e.g. In `b = [i+1.1 for i in tmp]`, comprehension will *always*<sup>1</sup> deduce the appropriate `eltype` of `b` for us:

```
julia> [i+1 for i in [1,2,3]]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2
 3
 4

julia> b = [i+1.1 for i in [1,2,3]]
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
 2.1
 3.1
 4.1
```

However, when using the common for-loops, we need to carefully initialize `b`(like the one in @Dan Getz's answer: `b = Vector{Int}(len)`), which means we need to explicitly do the type inference by ourselves. yes, Julia is dynamic language that talks about types, and it's not very hard to determine these types even in some sophisticated cases, but we just don't bother to.

---

<sub>1. Note that, in Juliav0.5- when Julia couldn't correctly do comprehension type inference in the global scope, this is actually a gotcha. But it's been fixed now, refer to [this PR](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/14782) and corresponding issues for further details.</sub>